# Grafana OnCall mobile app can’t scan QR-code

Tags: grafana

I installed grafana and oncall via docker compose on a vps in a private network. Oncall API URL looks like http://oncall:8888 (it is not visible from the internet). Connected in Grafana to oncall backend, alerting works.
Next I made a grafana cloud account, added the oncall API URL to docker-compose.yml (GRAFANA_CLOUD_ONCALL_API_URL: https://oncall-prod-eu-west-0.grafana.net/oncall)
Added a token in the cloud version, connected using this token in the OSS version. The OSS show me a QR code. And I can’t scan this code with 3 phones. No any errors. Nothing is happened.

Has anyone ever had this? Can I use mobile app by another way?

Should the OSS OnCall backend be visible from the outside? I don’t have it visible and grafana worked fine…

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your phone can't connect to your Oncall backend.

The documentation describes at [THIS](https://grafana.com/docs/oncall/latest/mobile-app/installation-and-setup/#connect-to-your-open-source-grafana-oncall-account) point that the phone and the backend must be on the same network. Since it is a Docker environment, you may need to open the port of the backend.
In the current OSS app version, a light gray "Error" text appears in the lower right corner, which further describes the problem.

Furthermore, you could use another QR code app to determine the content of the code and see which URL should be addressed.